# GA4 Client ID don't match the UA Client ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, clientid

I am having Issues with matching my Client IDs on GA4, with client IDs in UA. In order to see my client ids in GA4 explorer, and in UA custom reports, I added in the GTM config tag custom dimensions for the client ID, session ID and timestamp.

In the GTM debugger, and also in the console, I see how the Client ID is matching for what is sent to UA and GA4, but when I see the Ids in respective interface, there is not a single Client ID that matches.

What could possible be wrong?

thanks

The Javascript variable for grabbing the Client ID is this: (I don't know JavaScript)

```
function() { 
   return {{CK - Client ID}}.slice(6);
}
```

Grabbing the client ID with a first party cookie, _ga

Comment: We need to expand a little more the problem. the {} reffers to a another var with another code. you need to provide that.  the id is the _ga cookie value? this is stored in a CD wich scope? in GA4 is a custom var? what kind?

Comment: To add to Kemen's comment, please show how the IDs are different GA4 and UA store client ids slightly differently. Also, check if they really use the same variable to send the ID. Also, show your front-end debugging of the events before you go to the data. Plus, maybe the whole approach is wrong and it would be easier to inspect the raw data in BQ since it will show real client ids there.